# Getting a .Net application to close on crash

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a .NET 4 app running on Windows Server 2008 R2 which I use a separate running process to manage its life cycle (i.e., detect turn on / unexpected shutdown / reboot). This works fine for typical conditions. However, when the application throws an exception, Windows brings up the debug window offering to debug the application. I just want the application to crash, so the process runner can detect the crash and manage accordingly.

How do I allow an application to close on an exception?

Comment: do you know on what conditions the application crashes, if so do you have proper exception handling written?

Comment: Don't install Visual Studio on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a handler to the `Application.ThreadException` and in the handler, log the event, then exit nicely.

Also, add an event handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException as well.

[Unhandled Exceptions MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

Edit: removed bit about Handled flag.. thanks Alex

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line will prevent showing 'debug window'.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
```

Comment: This setting only affects Windows Forms exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a global exception handler or a try/catch to clean up the resources, log the error and close the app normally.

Comment: @Pedery Could you elaborate that?

Comment: Sure! Depends on if your application is performance critical though. The last one I worked on was a 3D CAD program and every mousemove generated lots of calculations. To have the performance-critical blocks spanned by *try* clauses has (apparently) a major impact on performance. Our code was stripped for all of this though.

Comment: @Pedery yes that may be true. But Jeff said a _global_ exception handler or (I assumed) _global_ try/catch block. Now that I read it again, I'm not sure if that was ment or it was me thinking it was ;-) Anyway, a global exception handler (like in `Main()` or so) will hardly have any performance effects measurable.

Comment: Maybe that's right and I haven't benchmarked. However, even if it's handled like proposed globally, you could expect a try/catch-like thing to enclose your code in the IL, which could perhaps be a culprit. Anyway, just speculating here now.

Comment: Right, I meant global handler or global catch block. Of course try/catch blocks have performance penalties. I don't know how error handlers are implemented in IL. I wouldn't be surprised if it was basically a global try/catch or something different. I've never had any performance issues with handling the `Application.OnError` event but I've never worked on anything nearly as fast as a 3D CAD application.